# Date formats and its difference in python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have two dates in below formats:

```
d1 = "Fri, 16 Oct 2015 18:06:37 +0530"
d2 = "Thu, 1 Oct 2015 17:12:00 +0530"
```

I need to find the number of days between these two dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the dateutil library:

```
from dateutil import parser

d1 = parser.parse("Fri, 16 Oct 2015 18:06:37 +0530")
d2 = parser.parse("Thu, 1 Oct 2015 17:12:00 +0530")

print d1-d2
print (d1-d2).days
```

output:

```
15 days, 0:54:37
15
```

Comment: Thanks Jon for giving it very clear. Any idea how to get the current date in python and what is its format. I have one format like "Fri, 16 Oct 2015 18:06:37 +0530" and another one is in current date from system. In that case how to get difference of days.

Comment: You can get the current date using datetime.datetime.today(), and then use the above method to subtract the two dates and get the number of days between the dates.

Answer (score -1):

Python 2.7.7

Code:

```
import datetime

# representing of your date strings
pattern = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +%f"

date_1_string = "Fri, 16 Oct 2015 18:06:37 +0530" 
date_2_string  = "Thu, 1 Oct 2015 17:12:00 +0530"

# parsing datetime objects from your strings
date_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_1_string, pattern)
date_2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_2_string, pattern)

# your date difference 
days_difference  = (date_1 - date_2).days # equal 15
```

More info about pattern formating you can find [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm)

Comment: You should explain your answer.

Comment: Sorry, its my first answer on stackoverflow.
I nead more practice

Comment: `+0530` is the offset not milleseconds